# Python Import Priority (Local vs other)

Tags: python, import, python-import

I recently cloned a git repo so that I could make custom changes to a Python library that I had previously just been importing. (The library is xmitgcm if people are curious, but I do not think this is important for my question.) If I type `import xmitgcm` while adding its local directory to the path, what will Python import?

Basically, I'm wondering if Python will check local files first or will default to the standard library people import.

Answer (score 0):

It will import your cloned copy, check [The Module Search Path](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) for more details on import priority.